# How does an AWS IoT device show as "connected"

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm following the `pubsub.py` example code for [AWS IoT using MQTT here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/blob/main/samples/pubsub.py). In particular I'm connecting to MQTT using the `awsiotsdk`.

That example works ok, but it connects to MQTT as a generic client, not as a specific device.

I would like to connect to MQTT to publish and subscribe as a specific device. In particular I want to be able to query for connected devices and see this device show up.

In the demo code I see that `--client-id` is included. By default it uses a UUID to generate a unique client ID for the demo. I've tried setting the `client-id` to the thing ARN `arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:123456789012:thing/test`

What I want/expect to see is the following search show the connected `thing`. The query comes back empty while the pubsub demo is running. The fact that it's empty tells me that the pubsub example is connecting as an MQTT client, not as a device. How do I connect as a device?

```
aws iot search-index --query-string connectivity.connected:true
{
    "things": []
}
```

Note that I have enabled `thingConnectivityIndexingMode=STATUS` via the AWS CLI.

---

Additional detail from comments:

From the docs:

> When the message broker receives a message published by a device or client, it republishes that message

It appears that I'm always connecting to MQTT (over WSS) as a "client". I don't see how to connect as a "device". The docs are maddeningly unspecific about this point. The `pubsub.py` example seems to connect as a generic "client", not as a particular "device".

I can and have registered the device via the AWS console or boto3 already.

Comment: Register your thing and follow the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-connect-devices.html . Get started at https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/aws/

Comment: I've added detail to the question quoting specific details from that page. I've read it over a few times, it doesn't disambiguate between connecting as a "client" vs. a registered "device". The `pubsub.py` example in the SDK seems to only connect as a "client". I'm left with the same question. How do I connect to MQTT (over WSS) as a "device" not just a generic "client"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clientId must equal the Thing name of a Thing registered in the Registry.

> The connectivity status data is indexed only for connections where the client ID has a matching thing name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/aggregation-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Amazing! I could have sworn I tried that, but apparently I didn't, or didn't do so correctly, it works perfectly with `--client test` where `test` is a registered thing.